# How Do I include MP3/Mp4s into my smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract, nft, metadata

How Do I include MP3/Mp4 capabilities in my smart contract?
Im interested in minting songs and short videos as CNFTs but I do not see any information online what so ever about how this can be done.  There are CNFT projects such as music box who seem to have accomplished this in a short format. Can anyone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

You would never include the actual mp3/mp4 in your smart contract. That's a lot of space (probably more than could ever fit on the chain) and unnecessary.

Instead, you could create a hash of the clip and attach that hash as metadata of an NFT--thus showing unique ownership. That's how NFTs for images/pictures work typically.

How you store the mp3/mp4 is up to you. You could host it on a website, or consider IPFS (InterPlanetary File System) for a bit more safety.

Comment: Thank you. I have been using pinata.cloud for an IPFS but it has trouble rendering even a small file. Do you have any IPFS's you'd recommend?

Comment: https://ipfs.io/ or you can use the Blockfrost API: https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/IPFS-Add

Answer (score 0):

So generally the media is stored somewhere else and you just link the NFT to it with a URL. If you didn't do this, the blockchain would grow astronomically.